# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. ( >TransformException, duplicate entry)

Tags: java, android

This is my build.gradle. I am getting the error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class

I tried many of the solutions given for the similar problem but nothing worked.How should I fix it?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
mavenLocal()
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    //all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
dexOptions{
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'



// Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'

// FirebaseUI

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Just add `multiDexEnabled true` in default configue .remove `=`

Comment: @MayurRaval , I did that but it is showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'google-gms'
}
```

Try such type in both fire base dependency. I am not sure but it may resolve.

Comment: I added that in both the firebase dependencies, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, somehow! I just changed the dependencies from

> ```
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0'
> ```